# custom home page and custom index page?

Tags: custom-post-types, homepage

I have a custom `home.php` design only for my homepage, also I have an `index.php` that made for page like: `http://example.com/page/11`

my problem is that for this page `http://example.com/page/11` WordPress load `home.php` how can I load `index.php` for this page?

Note: I don't want to use custom blog page like : `http://example.com/blog/page/11`

Note: I try front-page.php and it doesn't work too

Comment: _homepage.php_ does not exist in the [WP hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/), how are you linking it? Did you try _front-page.php_ instead?

Comment: @kero I edit question, I mean home.php

Comment: `front-page.php` is probably what you want ( is there a hyphen in the middle of the filename? )

Comment: @tom-j-nowell I try front-page.php and it doesn't work too.

Comment: `front-page.php` is for the immediate homepage, rather than the pagination, so put the contents of `home.php` into `front-page.php`, then put the contents of `index.php` in `home.php`

Comment: @TomJNowell Doesn't work. I put custom code for homepage in `front-page.php` than put regular `while loop` in `index.php` and `home.php` pages but still  `http://example.com/page/11` load `front-page.php` style and code.

Comment: Not a lot of code to go on here and also 'doesn't work' isn't really an informative explanation... ...what happens instead?